# Starting sas job from remote computer

Tags: sas

I have a scheduling program running on Server A running Windows 2008 RS. Server B is my SAS server under Windows 2008 R2. How do I kick-off a job on SAS server from my scheduling server? I can either use the sas.exe or a batch file to start my job. Owners of the SAS server tell me that I cannot add an application or Windows service to the SAS server. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a copy of my answer to a slightly different question (source: http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/260/hide-sas-batch-jobs-winxp).  I'm copy/pasting it here for perpetuity and also because it's more likely to help people searching:

---

You can use PsExec which is part of Microsoft/Sysinternals list of utility programs. This file will go on the scheduling server.  Grab it from here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

The tool is designed to allow you to execute jobs on remote machines. For example, if you want to launch a SAS program from the command line you could run:

```
psexec \\machinename sas.exe -sysin remotedrivename:\remotefolder\myprogram.sas
```

This would launch SAS.EXE on the remote machine and run the supplied program that exists on the remote machine. When it launches SAS it appears to launch it within a PsServ service. Because it's running within a service no interface will be displayed. I'm not even sure if you would see it appear as it's own process or application in windows task manager. If you use SysInternals other program, ProcessExplorer, instead of Task Manager you can see this happening.

Note that the REMOTE MACHINE and the LOCAL machine can be the same machine.

PROS: Many other uses for this technique. It's free. PsExec is only required on the machine that is making the call, not both machines.

CONS: Its a bit of a roundabout way to do things. Need to install a third party program (although it is now a MS tool). Some antivirus programs/network admins may not allow it.

Note that if your SAS jobs access network resources then you will probably need to make the network resource available first using the net map command. I suggest running your sas job in a batch file like so (or use the 'x' command from within your SAS file to call the 'net use' commands):

Command executed from local machine:

```
psexec \\machinename -sysin remotedrivename:\remotefolder\myprogram.BAT
```

Contents of batch file on remote machine:

```
net use m: \\fileserver\sharedfolder /USER:mynetworkdomainname\myusername mypassword
sas.exe -sysin remotedrivename:\remotefolder\myprogram.sas
net use m: /delete
```

Comment: +1, we use this approach in our Stored Process Web Application to allow the calling session to 'die' / continue..